# Server Side for Mobile App

Tags: objective-c, database, server

I am currently developing a mobile app that will essentially store photos and videos. I am thinking about using AWS to store the media and PostgreSQL to store other information. I was wondering if I should write a server side in another language? What are the pros/cons of writing a server side in another language? Or can I just use purely objective c or will that be bad?

Comment: Yes, you will need to write server code to handle the traffic, like your need, store and retrieve the information.

Answer (score 0):

Objective C isn't used for server side processing.  That will need to be written in golang, PHP, C#, Java, Ruby on Rails, PERL, etc. (whichever you prefer).  Check with your web host to see what languages are available on your account.

Simple scripts to read from/write to AWS are available in every language mentioned above.  Personally, I've used PHP and MySQL to do something similar, and then used the AFNetworking framework (in Objective C) to process that data within my iOS apps.

Comment: So do you think I should use AFNetworking to dave media to AWS and put/retrieve data from PostgreSQL in the server side?

Comment: Actually, I use PHP as a middleware layer for all web service transactions.  (I add the meta data info into the database, including a dynamically generated file path in AWS, and then I use the same PHP script to upload the posted image to AWS)

Comment: So do you handle everything database (insert and get) and AWS related stuff with PHP?

Comment: Yes.  That seems to be the easiest way for me.

Comment: Since i dont know PHP, do you think I should write the server side in Java or Go, and how do I communicate from the frontend (obj c) to a custom server side that I write

Comment: Do you know Java or Go?  I'd go with PHP mostly because there are *years* of tutorials and documentation doing this.  (There may be with Java as well -- I just don't know it as well)

Comment: yeah i alrdy know java and go

Comment: Then do it using go and post that somewhere so I can see how you do it!  :-)

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using BaaS (Backend as a Service) so you can focus on your client.

Example: http://api.shephertz.com/

Comment: You could also use Parse for this, which removes the need for a Postgres database.